# Running an each() on a result of another each() in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a mobile menu system for a website. Within the footer there are div's, with a class of `.footer_menu`. Within each of these div's is a ul with list of links relevant to this div.

What I would like to do is loop through each of these div's, which I can using the following:-

```
        $('.footer_menu').each(function () {
            var $linkCollection = $(this);
            // I would like to run something like
            ($linkCollection ul li).each(function(){
            code to go here to build menu. I can do this bit once I get the line above functioning.
            }
        })
```

Any necessarily looking for a solution, pointers in the right direction are fine.

Comment: Okay? What is it you're trying to *do* with the elements, once you've found them? If you're trying to rearrange the DOM (move elements from one place to another), or change the presentation of the elements, can you explain the desired end-result? What's your HTML?

Comment: You can do `$linkCollection.find('ul li').each()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$linkCollection.find('ul li').each(function(){ 
  // do your stuff here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, lets me do exactly what I need to.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul li', $(this)).each(function(){...
```

The format is `$(selector, context)`. This will find all `li` elements in `ul` elements in the current  `.footer_menu` iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends what you need to do. If you need to have access to the `$linkCollection` object, you could use nested `each` functions:

```
$('.footer_menu').each(function () {
    var $linkCollection = $(this);
    $linkCollection.find('ul li').each(function() {
        //do something here using $linkCollection
    });
});
```

Otherwise it would be much faster to do:

```
$('.footer_menu ul li').each(function() {
    //do something here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$('.footer_menu').each(function () {
    var $linkCollection = $(this);
    // I would like to run something like
    $linkCollection.find('ul li').each(function(){
        //code to go here to build menu. I can do this bit once I get the line above functioning.
    }
})
```